# Look up intervals from another data.table - by group

Tags: r, data.table, intervals

I have a Part A made up of 3 sections.
First I describe what I successfully do with this.
Then how I am unsuccessful with more Parts.

The Section lengths are in `data.table` `d1`.

```
library(data.table)

    d1 <- data.table(
            Part="A",
            Section=1:3,
            SecLen=c(10,30,9))
    d1
 #       Part Section SecLen
 #    1:    A       1     10
 #    2:    A       2     30
 #    3:    A       3      9
```

I also have a set of locations along the Part in `d2`.

```
d2 <- data.table(
        Part="A",
        PartLoc=c(0,7.5,10,20,35,45,49))
d2
#    Part PartLoc
# 1:    A     0.0
# 2:    A     7.5
# 3:    A    10.0
# 4:    A    20.0
# 5:    A    35.0
# 6:    A    45.0
# 7:    A    49.0
```

I want to add which Section each Location is in.

First I stack the Section Lengths in `d1` using `cumsum`

```
d1[,CumLen:=cumsum(SecLen)]
d1
   #    Part Section SecLen CumLen
   # 1:    A       1     10     10
   # 2:    A       2     30     40
   # 3:    A       3      9     49
```

Then I use `findInterval` to map the Section. Note that I want Location 10 to be assigned to Section 1, not 2.

```
d2[,Sec.fI:=findInterval(PartLoc,c(-1,d1$CumLen),left.open=TRUE)]
d2
    #    Part PartLoc Sec.fI
    # 1:    A     0.0      1
    # 2:    A     7.5      1
    # 3:    A    10.0      1
    # 4:    A    20.0      2
    # 5:    A    35.0      2
    # 6:    A    45.0      3
    # 7:    A    49.0      3
```

Another approach uses a `data.table` join.

First I add the start locations of each Section.

```
d1[,CumLen0:=c(-1,head(CumLen,-1))]
d1
    #    Part Section SecLen CumLen CumLen0
    # 1:    A       1     10     10      -1
    # 2:    A       2     30     40      10
    # 3:    A       3      9     49      40
```

Then look up the Section.

```
d2[,Sec.cs:=d1[d2,Section,on=.(CumLen0<PartLoc,CumLen>=PartLoc)]]
d2
    #    Part PartLoc Sec.fI Sec.cs
    # 1:    A     0.0      1      1
    # 2:    A     7.5      1      1
    # 3:    A    10.0      1      1
    # 4:    A    20.0      2      2
    # 5:    A    35.0      2      2
    # 6:    A    45.0      3      3
    # 7:    A    49.0      3      3
```

Either way works.

Now I try with more Parts.

```
D1 <- data.table(
 Part = c("A","A","A","B","B","C"),
 Section = c(1,2,3,1,2,1),
 SecLen = c(10,30,9,5,20,18) # incorrectly had 10 for the last value
)

D2 <- data.table(
 Part = c(rep("A",7),rep("B",3),rep("C",3)),
 PartLoc = c(0.0,7.5,10,20,35,45,49,1,12,25,0,9,18)
)

D1[,CumLen:=cumsum(SecLen),by=Part]
D1
#    Part Section SecLen CumLen
# 1:    A       1     10     10
# 2:    A       2     30     40
# 3:    A       3      9     49
# 4:    B       1      5      5
# 5:    B       2     20     25
# 6:    C       1     18     18

D2
    #     Part PartLoc
    #  1:    A     0.0
    #  2:    A     7.5
    #  3:    A    10.0
    #  4:    A    20.0
    #  5:    A    35.0
    #  6:    A    45.0
    #  7:    A    49.0
    #  8:    B     1.0
    #  9:    B    12.0
    # 10:    B    25.0
    # 11:    C     0.0
    # 12:    C     9.0
    # 13:    C    18.0
```

I try `findInterval`.

```
D2[,Sec.fI:=findInterval(PartLoc,c(-1,D1$CumLen),left.open=TRUE),by=Part]
# Error in findInterval(PartLoc, c(-1, D1$CumLen), left.open = TRUE) : 
#        'vec' must be sorted non-decreasingly and not contain NAs
```

Obviously it doesn't work because I haven't grouped `D1$CumLen` by Part, so it is non-decreasing.

I try the join.

```
D1[,CumLen0:=c(-1,head(CumLen,-1)),by=Part]

D2[,Sec.cs:=D1[D2,Section,on=.(CumLen0<PartLoc,CumLen>=PartLoc),by=Part]]
# Error in vecseq(f__, len__, if (allow.cartesian || notjoin || !anyDuplicated(f__,  : 
#   Join results in 31 rows; more than 19 = nrow(x)+nrow(i).
#   Check for duplicate key values in i each of which join to the same group in x over and over again. 
#   If that's ok, try by=.EACHI to run j for each group to avoid the large allocation. 
#   If you are sure you wish to proceed, rerun with allow.cartesian=TRUE. 
#   Otherwise, please search for this error message in the FAQ, Wiki, Stack Overflow and data.table issue tracker for advice.
```

Here I am running into the limits of my nascent knowledge of joins. I try `allow.cartesian=TRUE` as suggested, but I just confirm that I somehow got 31 rows and don't have what I want.

```
D1[D2,Section,on=.(CumLen0<PartLoc,CumLen>=PartLoc),by=Part,allow.cartesian=TRUE]
#     Part Section
#  1:    A       1
#  2:    A       1
#  3:    A       1
#  4:    A       2
#  5:    A       2
#  6:    A       3
#  7:    A       3
#  8:    A       1
#  9:    A       2
# 10:    A       2
# 11:    A       1
# 12:    A       1
# 13:    A       2
# 14:    B       1
# 15:    B       2
# 16:    B       2
# 17:    B       2
# 18:    B       1
# 19:    B       2
# 20:    B       2
# 21:    B       1
# 22:    B       2
# 23:    B       2
# 24:    C       1
# 25:    C       1
# 26:    C       1
# 27:    C       1
# 28:    C       1
# 29:    C       1
# 30:    C       1
# 31:    C       1
# Part Section
```

I'd appreciate help getting this to work in `data.table`.

**Edit**
I am satisfied with the `findInterval` solution by @Ian Campbell. I would still be interested in seeing how to make the join work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could subset `D1` with the `.BY` special symbol:

```
library(data.table)
D2[,Sec.fI:=findInterval(PartLoc,c(-1,D1[Part == .BY,CumLen]),left.open=TRUE),by=Part][]
    Part PartLoc Sec.fI
 1:    A     0.0      1
 2:    A     7.5      1
 3:    A    10.0      1
 4:    A    20.0      2
 5:    A    35.0      2
 6:    A    45.0      3
 7:    A    49.0      3
 8:    B     1.0      1
 9:    B    12.0      2
10:    B    25.0      2
11:    C     0.0      1
12:    C     9.0      1
13:    C    18.0      2
```

See `help("special-symbols")` for more info.

Comment: Thank you. I don't see how `.GRP` is mapped to Part. In your output (which I can reproduce), rows 6 and 7 should be in Section (A)3 and rows 9 and 10 in Section (B)2

Comment: My mistake, I often mix up the `.BY` and `.GRP` special symbols. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes indeed.  The only flaw is that row 13 goes to a non-existent Section 2, because I had a typo and made the length 10 instead of 18. I'll edit my post.

Answer (score 1):

A bit lost in your OP. At least based on the first 3 sentences, here is an option using rolling join:

```
d1[, LastPage := cumsum(SecLen)]
d2[, Section := 
  d1[.SD, on=.(Part, LastPage=PartLoc), roll=-Inf, Section]
]
```

output:

```
   Part PartLoc Section
1:    A     0.0       1
2:    A     7.5       1
3:    A    10.0       1
4:    A    20.0       2
5:    A    35.0       2
6:    A    45.0       3
7:    A    49.0       3
```

**Edit by OP:**

I can confirm this works for my case with more Parts.

```
D2[, Sec.rJ := 
       D1[.SD, on=.(Part, CumLen=PartLoc), roll=-Inf, Section]
   ][]
    #     Part PartLoc Sec.rJ
    #  1:    A     0.0      1
    #  2:    A     7.5      1
    #  3:    A    10.0      1
    #  4:    A    20.0      2
    #  5:    A    35.0      2
    #  6:    A    45.0      3
    #  7:    A    49.0      3
    #  8:    B     1.0      1
    #  9:    B    12.0      2
    # 10:    B    25.0      2
    # 11:    C     0.0      1
    # 12:    C     9.0      1
    # 13:    C    18.0      1
```

Comment: Thank you. I confirm this works for my case with multiple Parts.

Comment: I was puzzled by the unnamed argument "Section" at the end. I guess it is the `j` part, since `D2[, Sec.rJ := D1[.SD, Section, on=.(Part, CumLen=PartLoc), roll=-Inf]][]` works as well. It's curious how the order of arguments works here.

Comment: I am trying to figure out the `.SD` in the `i` position. Is it evaluated in `D1` or `D2`? If I omit it, `D2[, Sec.rJ := D1[, Section, on=.(Part, CumLen=PartLoc), roll=-Inf]][]`, I get the right answer except for one row - Location 12.0 on Part B incorrectly maps to Section 1. Interesting.

Comment: @DaveTurek, yeah it is part of `j` and the spacing is for improving readability. `.SD` refers to d2. It should not work when you omit `.SD`. I get an error when i omit `.SD`: `Error in `[.data.table`(d1, , Section, on = list(Part, CumLen = PartLoc),  : 
  Attempting to do natural join but no common columns in provided tables`

Comment: Thank you @chinsoon12. Your error without `.SD` might be due to inconsistencies in our datasets and naming. I am using my full sets `D1` and `D2` rather than the one-Part sets `d1` and `d2`, plus I named the cumulative sum `CumLen` rather than `LastPage`.